# How to extract int values from a Bit Array

Tags: ios, objective-c, byte, bit

Here is what I am facing right now :

- I have an NSData that contains 16 bytes
- Each 2 bytes contain 3 values (1 value on 2bits another on 8, and the last on 6)
- I need to extract those 3 values from this NSData.

Right now I am able to get all the bytes, I don't know how to get my 3 values...

[image]

Help me stackoverflow user, you are my only hope :)

Comment: `val1 = arr[0] & 00111111b`, basically.e xtract the individual bytes and do some bit fiddling.

Comment: Hi Marc,

First of all, thanks for your answer.

I get that this would extract my "Value1" from my "byte0", but how can I extract my value2, which is in between my "byte0" and my "byte1" ?

Comment: extract byte 0, bit shift the last two bits down, extract byte 1, shift up two bits, then bitwise-AND the two values togther. somethign like `(byte[0] & 011000000b) >> 6) | (byte[1] & 000011111b) << 2)`, though that's just off the top of my head

Comment: @MarcB Why aren't you posting these comments as an answer?